# How can I see how many league games I lost in Starcraft 2?

Tags: starcraft-2

One change in [patch 1.3](http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/blog/2514162#blog) was that "Loss counts are no longer displayed in Profile and Ladder pages for players below Master League."

Are they displayed anywhere else? While I might understand that I can't see this information for somebody else, I would really like to know how *my own* win/loss ratio is. I want to see if I'm doing well, and knowing how many games I lost seems to be important for that.

Can I somehow find out how many games of each kind I played in total, or how many I lost?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [sc2gears](http://sites.google.com/site/sc2gears/) to analyze your own replays. You can do a search filter on 1v1 "AutoMM" game types and do a multi-rep analysis which gives you all the statistics and graphs you could wish for, including win/loss/ratio.

I think this illustrates why it's important to keep all of your replays: Battle.net is not an open data source; they can show / hide anything any time they want. To see un-tampered-with analysis of your games, your replay archive is the best source.

It's too bad sites like http://sc2ranks.com will also hide the losses; they should theoretically be able to deduce your loss count from your recent games played even though battle.net doesn't give that metric explicitly. I guess it's not 100% guaranteed accurate...

---

[update] More of a commentary to your question: As far as "Am I doing well?" honestly your win/loss ratio is of little use, because battle.net tries to match you with equally ranked players (thus trying to keep your ratio ~50% no matter your skill level). If you are improving faster than your moving MMR rating is rising, the ratio will theoretically go up, but that's only in theory. Bnet could just as easily randomly pair you with 10 favored opponents you will lose to.

Another reason why win/loss ratio is a bad metric to judge improvement: Part of getting better is to focus on the things you're bad at, which means during *practice* you will not win as often. As most of us "practice" on the ladder itself, our **win/loss ratio would inaccurately imply that the more you practice, the worse you are**.

Comment: You really shouldn't be practicing on the Ladder though.  I would think that anything that could adjust your MMR negatively, as practicing on the ladder would do, would be something to avoid.

Comment: Obviously if you consider ladder play only "performance" play, then ignore my comment.

Comment: I have more then 2 hundred games played on ladder, do you think I should keep all of them? I upload some of them into sc2replay... but keep all - seems like crazy...

Comment: I don't see any downside to keeping them all - they are very small files, and sc2gears analyzes them at lightning speed. Of course that's easy for me to say -- I have a compulsive need to archive stuff.

Comment: That sc2gears program is very neat.